Which order for check valve and ball valve?
I am installing a check valve in my main water supply line, after the meter (utility owned on the public road) and the utility owned shutoff valve and an additional existing gate valve on the house exterior.
When installing the check valve, I am also adding a ball valve, first, since I’m already opening the line, might as well and it’s better than the old gate valve and second, since a Sharkbite slipping version exists, it saves me an additional slip coupling.
But, in the direction of flow, should the ball valve or check valve go first?

Doesn't really matter to the water. Might affect maintainability.

Aside: Do you have a water heater? Does it have an expansion tank?

@keshlam Same goes for electricity. Yet there are tons of things to get wrong and/or do right (e.g. daisychaining vs wirenuts). I have no experience in plumbing which is why I am asking here. If it really doesn't matter at all, that's also a valid answer.

@HABO . Yes, I have and yes I have an expansion tank. I assume you are asking to make sure I have one since I am installing the check valve?

@jsotola I don't. Otherwise I wouldn't ask this question here :-)

I would have the water hit the ball valve first. That way it can be used to conveniently turn off flow  if the check valve needs maintenance. The reverse doesn't give you that one extra controlled point
(I don't entirely trust my old main valve and at some point want to replace it with a ball valve. Hadn't considered adding a check valve while I was at it...)
To make it explicit: I don't think code has any opinion on this, so this is strictly my own best opinion. Others will probably disagree.

as long as you add an expansion tank as well as the check valve and keep in mind that the expansion tank needs replacement regularly.  Get a y strainer while you are at it.

@keshlam it seems the order is preference and not “best practice” or even code? In this case, could you add this for clarification & completeness?

@FreshCodemonger hmm I didn’t know these. Y strainer seems not easy. I can’t find a SharkBite version but for my first plumbing project (incl being in crawl space at main water line) I feel comfortable only with SharkBite

You can use sb MIP couplings.  threaded fittings are pretty easy just use teflon and pipe dope - worst case you just unthread and redo it.  watch a few videos on teflon so you roll it off the back and wrap properly ( good skill to have anyway ).  Could always add later too.
